# Does active job call after_perform when perform raises an error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activejob

The rails documentation does not specify if callbacks are called if an exception in raised during job performance. Can anyone confirm this behavior?

Sub question, does the behavior change if one implements a rescue_from?

What if an error is thrown in rescue_from?

Answer (score 4):

In active job, after_perform will not be called if an error is raised. I did not see it in the documentation either, but error handling in active jobs is either done manually (possibly by implementing a rescue_from) or it is handled by the active job adapters. I know for the delayed job adapter the job will retry a couple of times if an error is raised during perform and it will never get to the after_perform.

Answer (score 1):

`after_perform` is not executed if an error is raised during the execution of `perform`, even if it is rescued with `rescue_from`.

#### Without an error

```rb
class FooJob < ActiveJob::Base
  after_perform do |job|
    puts 'after perform'
  end

  def perform
    puts "during perform"
  end
end
```

```rb
> FooJob.perform_now
during perform
after perform
```

#### With an error

```rb
class FooJob < ActiveJob::Base
  after_perform do |job|
    puts 'after perform'
  end

  def perform
    puts "during perform"
    raise "error during perform"
  end
end
```

```rb
> FooJob.perform_now
during perform
# ... trace
RuntimeError (error during perform)
```

#### With an error and rescue

```rb
class FooJob < ActiveJob::Base
  rescue_from(StandardError) do |exception|
    puts 'rescuing standard error: ' + exception.message
  end

  after_perform do |job|
    puts 'after perform'
  end

  def perform
    puts "during perform"
    raise StandardError, "error during perform"
  end
end
```

```rb
> FooJob.perform_now
during perform
# ... trace
rescuing standard error: error during perform
#<StandardError: error during perform>
```